# Implemetation of BAT algorithm in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have implemented BAT Algorithm in Scala (I am interested in functional programming style).Steps involved in BAT algorithm are

[image]

Parameters of BAT algorithm are

[image]

- x : Position of BAT

My Code is working fine without any errors but its output is not desired one as there is no change in position of BAT's after specified iteration. I am wondering where things are wrong in code. My code is below.
I also want to remove while loop so that code become pure functional in style.

Comment: Am I the only one who has never heard of the "BAT algorithm"? Google search finds million references to ["Bat algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat_algorithm), but even after searching, I still have no idea what the "BAT" algorithm is supposed to be? Also, are you sure that the question doesn't rather belong to Code Review Stack Exchange?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin simply saying, BAT is one of meta-heuristic for optimization technique that is developed based on echolocation behavior of BAT's

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and step through your code? The answer may become apparant to you. If you are not using an IDE (e.g. Intelli-J), then get one! Life will be much easier for you.

Comment: @GMc i am already using Intelli-J , also debug the code but can find the bug

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it is, but it appears that when *single stepping* through your program that these lines of code reset your positions back to their original values:

```scala
        if(math.random > j.PulseRate  ){
          j.position = j.BestPosition + (Bandwidth * sum / N) //sum/d is mean of Loudness , where N is number of BAT's
        }
```

If you comment this block of code out, then your positions do change. As I am not a bat expert, I have no idea if the change is correct or not, but they do change.

Hopefully this is sufficient to debug your algorithm correctly.

Comment: But this condition is necessary to apply

Comment: Maybe so, but that is what is resetting your values. I am unable to debug your program for you. I have, but probably shouldn't have, isolated one area where there is a problem. You need to work out why that calculation is resetting your location values. Again the debugger will be helpful; or simply print all of the values out and see what is happening.

Comment: I will again use debugger to check the values. One more question is is this code pure in functional style? second one is how to replace while loop so that i can achieve parallelism?