# Replacement of if with higher order method

Tags: scala, functional-programming, distributed-computing

using if block in scala for distributed computing is least recommended. I have  code and i want to replace if with Scala higher order method. How can i do that.
Detail code is given [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56414512/implemetation-of-bat-algorithm-in-scala)

Some part of code that contains if block is.

```
var bat = DenseVector.fill(N)(new BAT12(d , MinVal , MaxVal ))
bat.foreach{x => x.BestPosition = x.position;x.fitness =  Sphere(x.position)  ; x.BestFitness = x.fitness}
bat.foreach(x =>
if(x.BestFitness < GlobalBest_Fitness)
{
 GlobalBest_Fitness =x.BestFitness ;GlobalBest_Position = x.BestPosition
})
```

Comment: The problem is not the `if`, the problem is using a mutable data structure. And this has nothing to do with distributed computing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
bat.filter(_.BestFitness < GlobalBest_Fitness).foreach { x =>
  GlobalBest_Fitness = x.BestFitness
  GlobalBest_Position = x.BestPosition
}
```

Comment: Solution is fine but filter works with List,Array , does not work with DenseVector

Comment: Try calling `toArray` or `toScalaVector` on `DenseVector` like so `bat.toArray.filter(...`

Answer (score 1):

Do a filter before the foreach, with the if condition as the filter condition. Then do the foreach without any condition.